# Print HTML/PHP using WAMP on Lan

Tags: php, android, html, wamp

I have installed WAMP on Computer whose IP is 192.168.1.1 and Printer is connected to same Computer
using USB.
And have configured WAMP so that my Android Device can access Server (WAMP) through WiFi,

```
i.e. http://192.168.1.1/myproject/print.php
```

My Android device ip is 192.168.1.2

What i want is to print data which is fetched from DB using PHP file, through Android device directly.

Please help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at the docs for printing

http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

However you should at least attempt to create an application and post this code to Stackoverflow for better feedback

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i think only some wireless Printers and LAN connected printers can print through Android. i need a functionality to print using USB connected printer.